# Toggle button collapse not working in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

My toggle button is not working when the navbar collapses. I have checked the data-target several times and looks ok.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" title="The Title">
    <img style="max-width:100px;" src="images/LOGO-4.png">
  </a>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Thanks so much, that's working now. I think my jquery links weren't correct. Was also missing an closing div tag after my 'a class' element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course your toggle button will differ based on your screen resolution.                Try something along the lines of:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


     </head>
<body >

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" title="The Title">
    <img style="max-width:100px;" src="images/LOGO-4.png">
  </a>
</div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Try this out on your mobile and see. Afterwards go into your css file and set the properties for screen size on WHEN should the toggle button appear to be.
The toggle button might not appear on the desktop until you change these properties, or resize your browser window smaller, and smaller until the toggle button appears.

Eg. Maximized on my browser window, the toggle button doesn't appear.
[image: Toggle bar not shown]
However if you resize your browser window by half(or if you're surfing on a phone), it'll look like this
[image: When on mobile or a reduced browser size]

To fix this you'll need to go into your css settings. But this is ONLY if you want to change it. Otherwise it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's working now. I think my jquery links weren't correct. Was also missing an closing div tag after my 'a class' element.

Answer (score 3):

See that you have correct import of library, i hade a same problem, i dont why sometimes it has strange behavior with different version of Jquery

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, I think my jquery link was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Every time we are facing this problem "why is navbar-toggle button not working?", but this time we have found the solution and specially thanks for google chrome developer team for developed showing error clearly.

We should include jquery library file before bootstrap javascript file.

Comment: Thanks, it was really my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help because I had the same problem and fixed it by this:

```
<body>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         ...
     </nav>

     <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Default navbar - Requires JavaScript plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap